# Como buscar algo em 100% do banco MySQL

Tags: mysql

Existe uma query MySQL em que eu possa buscar em todos os dados de todas as tabelas de um banco de uma unica vez?

Equivalente a algo como isso:

```
"SELECT todos_os_campos FROM todas_as_tabelas WHERE qualquer_campo = 'isso'"
```

Comment: Está em `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` todas as colunas de todas as tabelas  [ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html ] , agora qual delas está os dados eu não sei.

Comment: Me explique melhor sua necessidade, já fiz um script para ver se existia um dado em qualquer coluna de qualquer tabela do banco, onde eu retornava onde encontrava tal registro, se for isso posso te ajudar

Comment: @arllondias Exemplo, eu tenho um banco, e preciso percorrer todos os registros desse em banco de dados em busca de todas as vezes que um registro possui o valor  = 'valorX' e devolver a linha com o valor.

Comment: @Everson acredito que seja por aí mesmo, mas não localizei como fazer, por isso fiz a pergunta kk

Comment: Ok, vou fazer o script já coloco como resposta.

Comment: Eu não vou responder no momento porque teria que fazer testes, mas logo lhe digo que `UNION` não seria algo fácil de trabalhar, ainda mais se as tabelas forem totalmente diferentes, se elas forem parecidas/iguais até que funciona bem, e mesmo que houvesse uma solução funcional especifica ainda sim creio eu que a solução provavelmente (e relativamente) mais performatica seria fazer query por query e agrupar estes dados depois via PHP, pegando somente o que é interessante. Não posso afirmar nada com precisão, pois geralmente dependeria de criar testes, o que não posso fazer no momento.

Comment: algumas alternativas em(ingles) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesta Procedure ele procura em todos os campos que não são numéricos determinado conteúdo, primeiro parâmetro você passa o que quer buscar e no segundo o nome do banco de dados, ele vai retornar todos os resultados encontrados. em consultas separadas, porque não tem como dar um UNION ALL porque as tabelas não possuem o mesmo número de colunas. Segue o Código:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_search_data;        

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_search_data(p_conteudo TEXT,                                                                        
                                p_nome_banco TEXT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_nome_tabela TEXT;
    DECLARE v_nome_coluna TEXT;
    DECLARE v_possui_registro INT;
    DECLARE v_fim INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur_tabelas CURSOR FOR SELECT  TABLE_NAME,                                                                              
                                           COLUMN_NAME
                                    FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`                                                                           
                                   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = p_nome_banco
                                     AND NUMERIC_PRECISION IS NULL;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_fim = 1;

    OPEN cur_tabelas;

    REPEAT

        IF NOT v_fim THEN
        FETCH cur_tabelas INTO v_nome_tabela, v_nome_coluna;

        SET @v_possui_registro = 0;
        SET @v_select = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @v_possui_registro
                                  FROM ',v_nome_tabela,'
                                 WHERE ', v_nome_coluna,' = "',p_conteudo,'"');

        PREPARE stmt_select FROM @v_select;
        EXECUTE stmt_select;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_select;

        IF @v_possui_registro > 0 THEN

            SET @v_resultado = CONCAT('SELECT *
                                         FROM ',v_nome_tabela,'
                                        WHERE ', v_nome_coluna,' = "',p_conteudo,'"');
            PREPARE stmt_resultado FROM @v_resultado;
            EXECUTE stmt_resultado;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_resultado;
        END IF;

    END IF;
   UNTIL v_fim END REPEAT;
   CLOSE cur_tabelas;


END
|
DELIMITER ;

-- CALL sp_search_data('TESTE', 'banco_teste');
```

Lembrando que nessa procedure podem ser feitas várias implementações, como imprimir o nome da tabela e coluna que foi encontrado o registro, imprimir a query que foi feita entre outras coisas interessantes, fica ai como ideia inicial essa estrutura.

Comment: Vou testar daqui a pouquinho, ja aceito se deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Bom, nativo o `SQL` não possui esse recurso, mas se você quer fazer um `SELECT` em todas as tabelas em uma query só pode usar o `UNION` para trazer os registros em uma só query.

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela_1 WHERE condicao = 1
UNION  
SELECT * FROM Tabela_2 WHERE condicao = 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM Tabela_3 WHERE condicao = 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM Tabela_4 WHERE condicao = 4
UNION
...
// assim por diante com todas as tabelas
```

Sei que dessa forma pode ser **inviável** se você tiver 10.000 tabelas, mas eu te dou essa opção contando que seja viável para você fazer dessa forma.

Comment: X tabelas * Y colunas = Z comparações, acho nem um pouco viável mesmo. Então, não é mais fácil criar uma função/procedimento que gera isso automaticamente para não fazer na mão?

Comment: O processo poderia ser automatizado com um script que faz um "SELECT * FROM tabela_x" e passa por todas as tabelas.

Comment: Apesar de dar certo, é inviável isso, pois vai se tratar de um mecanismo para varrer um DB mutável.